# specific group in t-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by

Is anybody to know how to get result in this example in T-SQL:

```
id val1 val2
1.  a   b
1.  c   d
1.  b   a
1.  d   c
1.  e   f
2.  k   m
2.  m   p
2.  m   k
```

```
id val1 val2
1.  a   b
1.  c   d
1.  e   f
2.  k   m
2.  m   p
```

a  b and b  a group only in a b. The same for c d (d c) and k m (m k)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number` with a custom `partition by`.

```
select id,val1,val2
from (select id,val1,val2,
      row_number() over(partition by id,case when val1<val2 then val1 else val2 end
                                       ,case when val1>val2 then val1 else val2 end 
                        order by val1) as rnum
      from tbl
     ) t
where rnum=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this as:

```
select id, val1, val2
from t
where val1 < val2
union all
select id, val1, val2
from t
where val1 > val2 and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.id = t.id and t2.val1 = t.val2 and t2.val2 = t.val1);
```